# Fast inverse of asymmetric diagonally dominant matrix with diagonal 1 and non-positive off-diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, matrix-inverse

I am interested in ways to obtain (even approximately) the inverse of an asymmetric diagonally dominant matrix with diagonal 1 and non-positive off-diagonals.
Formally, let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix over the reals, where $A_{ii} = 1, \forall i$, and $A_{ij} \leq 0, \forall i\neq j$, and $\sum_{j\neq i} |A_{ij}| \leq A_{ii}$, $\forall i$. Also, we can decompose $A$ as $A = I - M$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $M$ is a non-negative matrix such that $\sum_{j\neq i} M_{ij} \leq 1$.

Is there a method better than $O(n^3)$ to compute $A^{-1}$ or $(I-M)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no magic bullet method (apart from general Strassen-type algorithms that usually do not pay out in practice). Or, at least, if it existed, many of my colleagues and I would be surprised and happy to know about it. :)

You can truncate the Neumann series $A^{-1} = I + M + M^2 + \dots$, but this is going to be a poor approximation unless $\|M\| \ll 1$. Or use generic iterative methods to solve linear systems, e.g. Arnoldi, if you have a matrix so that they converge fast (one with clustered eigenvalues, for instance).

On the other hand, you may be interested in knowing that there are methods for solving such linear systems much more *accurately* than for general matrices; google for "GTH-like method". Assuming you know the diagonal excess $M\mathbf{1}$, they can reach $O(n^3)\mathsf{u}$ relative accuracy on all matrices irrespective of their condition number (impressively).